# how to make card deck and carousel overlapped

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

soo im trying to make a website that look like this
[image]

u can see theres a white background between my yellow background and my carousel. is there anyway to make the background behind my card deck not white instead the same color my carousel?

HTML

```
<div class="row-lg" id="backcolor">
  <div class="card-deck mx-auto" id="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" id="cardbody1">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="cardtitle1">Card 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="cardtext1">Card text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" id="cardbody2">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="cardtitle2">Card 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="cardtext2">Card text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" id="cardbody3">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="cardtitle3">Card 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="cardtext3">Card text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" id="cardbody4">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="cardtitle4">Card 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="cardtext4">Card text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" id="cardbody5">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="cardtitle5">Card 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="cardtext5">Card text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#card-deck {
  padding-top: 190px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#card-deck .card {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#card-deck .card h5 {
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your jsfiddle or codepen link? @Frsal

Comment: can you please create snippet for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: We need to make your card container float over the two elements, because setting background-color to the card element, covers the background below it.

To do this, we need modify the #card-deck

- `position:relative` so we could adjust its position according to its parent div
- add `top:30px;` to position it 30px below its initial position
- remove the height and padding properties as we're going to rely on the cards' height
- add `z-index:1` to position it over the other elements

Use this css for the `#card-deck`

```
#card-deck {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/8y4ojb5t/

Comment: thanks for responding, but backcolor is what i did at first but it didnt show anything

Comment: Have you tried setting it with !important?
`background-color:#F0F0F0 !important;`

Comment: If that wouldn't work, will you update your html to include your header? If you could make it a working snippet, that would be better.

Comment: dude thanks for the answer, it work but if i resize my window the "about" on carousel overlap with the card, is it because the card or the carousel image is to small?

Comment: @Frsal I can't really replicate that as I don't have a working carousel on the fiddle. Can you modify the fiddle to contain the photos and the carousel?

Comment: okay heres the fiddle with the background picture in it : https://jsfiddle.net/2ok701zv/5/.

Comment: heres what i get in my localhost : https://i.postimg.cc/brDxV5Q1/Capture3.png and this is what its look like when the windows is halfed : https://i.postimg.cc/GmJkfGsg/Capture4.png

Answer (score -1):

Its because you forgot `#` to `background-color`.

Your css:

```
#backcolor{
    background-color: F1F0F0;
}
```

Use this:

```
#backcolor{
    background-color: #F1F0F0;
}
```

Your image is cutting because of `container-fluid` 's padding left and right. So you have to remove that padding.

Try this css:

```
 .container-fluid{
         padding-left: 0;
         padding-right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply, but i did do what u told, its just cut the background image above the card deck, here what happen : https://jsfiddle.net/oaL3m70p/